# Group Files Equally Based on Size into 'n' number of groups

Tags: windows, cmd

I am using the following command to generate list of files based on name...

```
dir [folder_location] /b >[output_file_name.txt]
```

How do I group them into 'n' groups such that total size is similar for each groups... ?

**[Update]** For eg: There are 1000 files I have to give to 100 people for re-editing. I want each of them to get a total of approx same amount of text to edit. Such that no person is unlucky with too much and the other lucky with too less.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`/o:s`](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) option for [`dir`](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html). To group the files together you will have to do some parsing of the information using a [`for /f`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) loop, check the size output for the file using `%%~zA`, and create separations at that point.

Here is an example that will output the `filepath = size`, excluding directories, and sorted from largest to smallest.

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in (`dir /b /o:-s /a:-d`) do echo.%%~dpnA = %%~zA
```

Answer (score 0):

**First attempt that groups files by size ranges**
*(It turns out this is not what the OP wanted)*

Here is one method. You can adjust the group definitions as needed. It is important that the group limits are listed in descending numeric order, and the last group must be 0.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "folder=test"
set "out=fileGroups.txt"
(
  pushd "%folder%"
  for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d /os "*"') do (
    set "class="
    for %%A in (
      "100000  [>= 100,000]      "
      "10000   [10,000 - 99,999] "
      "1000    [1,000 - 9,999]   "
      "100     [100 - 999]       "
      "0       [< 100]           "
    ) do for /f "tokens=1*" %%B in (%%A) do (
      if not defined class if %%~zF geq %%B (
        echo %%C %%~nxF
        set class=1
      )
    )
  )
  popd
)>"%out%"
type "%out%"
```

**Second attempt that divides files into n group of roughly equal total file length**
 *(This is what the OP is asking for)*

It is simple to assign all files to a group by using the modulo (remainder) operator on the line number. The files could simply be sorted by size, but then the 1st group would always get the smallest file in any group of *n*, and the last group would get the largest. The groups would not be equitable.

Assuming there is a random distribution of file sizes, what is wanted is to rotate which group gets the smallest and the largest for any specific group of *n*. The solution is suprisingly easy with a bit of math.

The following code assigns numbers 1 through 25 to one of 5 different groups, writing the number to a group file. The sum for each group is 65.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
del group*.txt
for /l %%N in (1 1 25) do (
  set /a "group=((%%N-1)+(%%N-1)/5)%%5+1"
  echo %%N >>group!group!.txt
)
```

The final answer simply applies the above to a list of files, sorted by size. The names are piped through FINDSTR to assign a "line number" to each file. Since the list is sorted by file size, the "line number" sorts the same as the file sizes.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "inFolder=test"
set "outFolder=groups"
set "groups=5"
pushd "%inFolder%"
2>nul del "%outFolder%\group*.txt"
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in ('dir /b /a-d /os "*"^|findstr /n "^"') do (
  set "file=%%B"
  set /a "group=((%%A-1)+(%%A-1)/groups)%%groups+1"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  >>"!outFolder!\group!group!.txt" echo !file!
  endlocal
)
popd
```

Comment: @DebajyotiDas - I understand your requirement now. I've updated my answer.